# Prove the power series $ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{k}}{k(k+1)} $ converges uniformly on $-1 \leq x \leq 1$.

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, uniform-convergence

I am trying to prove that the power series
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{k}}{k(k+1)}
$$
converges uniformly on $-1 \leq x \leq 1$.

---

I am planning to use the Weierstrass-M test. This means that if
$$
|u_{k}(x)| \leq m_{k}
$$
for all $x$ in some interval $I$, with $m_{k} \geq 0$, and if then
$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} m_{k} <\infty
$$
converges, then the series
$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} u_{k} (x) = f(x)
$$
converges uniformly.

---

Now I argue as follows:

We look at the *hardest* part to show convergence, hence that is at the points where the terms are largest, i.e. at $x=-1$ and $x=1$. Now we take $x = 1$. We then find
$$
\left| \frac{x^{k}}{k(k+1)} \right| \leq \left| \frac{1}{k(k+1)} \right| = \left| \frac{1}{k^{2} + k} \right| \leq \left| \frac{1}{k^{2}} \right| = m_{k} ,
$$
which implies
$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} m_{k} =  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^{2}}  = \frac{\pi^2}{6}< \infty
$$
and we conclude that indeed the power series converges uniformly.

---

Now my question is: is my reasoning correct? It feels very obvious and I am not sure if what I wrote is valid.

Comment: yes it's correct.

Comment: $ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^{2}}  $ is not $2$, otherwise it is correct.

Comment: Thanks. And indeed, I was thinking of $\frac{1}{2^{k}}$. It is now edited.

Answer (score 2):

Your reasoning is correct. The exact value of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty m_k$ is not relevant for the M-test, only that the series is convergent.

You could also choose
$$
\left| \frac{x^{k}}{k(k+1)} \right| \leq  \frac{1}{k(k+1)} = m_k
$$
for the comparison, that is a telescoping series:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty m_k = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1}\right) = 1
$$